# Get User's first and last name via Google API

Tags: google-chrome, oauth, google-api, gmail-api

Currently I am developing a Chrome-GMAIL extension which requires me to get the logged in user's first and last names. For experimentation, I have used the following goggle API (userinfo) and have successfully obtained the names I wanted:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
```

However, using the userinfo APIs will cause a change in the OAuth2 scopes in my manifest. This change will in turn cause a permission-prompt to my existing users (if a domain wide delegation is not setup in place). Point being the idea of having more prompts in front of my user, or additional oauth scope is not really something I desire.

Currently our extensions use the following OAuth scopes and API :

- Chrome's Identity API
- Chrome's Storage API
- GMAIL.modify
- GMAIL.send

My question is, is it possible to get the first and last names using an API that is defined/allowed/provided for by any of the above scopes/permissions I listed? or is userinfo the only way to go?

Thank you very much.

Comment: If you want profile info then you need to use one of the profile scopes and either go though the people api or the userinfo endpoint.  even https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users/getProfile wont give you the name of the user.

Comment: Yeah like i said i think you are going to need to request the profile scope or https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile  to get this information.

Comment: Thanks @DaImTo. I was just hoping there was some other way. thank you again.

Comment: You would need an OAuth manager to make request to the Gmail and Google Profile APIs. May I recommend you [Pizzly](https://github.com/bearer/pizzly), which is an open-source project that works really great from a frontend perspective.

Answer (score 3):

Profile data like first name and last name is private data. You are corect that some Google apis give you access to some data that would normally require an extra scope.  For email normally you would need to to request the email scope to get this back however the Gmail api does have an endpoint [getprofile](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users/getProfile) which will return the current users email address without you requesting the email scope.

However i am not aware of any apis that will give you access to the users first and last name without you requesting the profile or user.profile scope.

If you do decide to add the scope, I do recommend going though the people api rather then the userinfo endpoint as the data returned by the user info endpoint is not guaranteed  to always return the name.